# Rotation around custom axis with Quarternions

Tags: vectors, rotations

I am trying to set up a pitch yaw roll style rotation for a programming project. Currently, I'm rotating defining each axis of rotation as:

```
Yaw Axis   = (0,0,1)
Pitch Axis = (0,1,0)
Roll Axis  = (1,0,0)
```

My issue is that when the object 'rolls' it should then pitch in the axis relative to it's new rotation, however as I'm always defining the axis for pitch as (0,1,0) it always pitches up or down, regardless of orientation. How do I calculate the axis that is perpendicular to my objects new rotation?

Cheers!
Kaine

Comment: roll your three axes at the same time when you are rolling the object

Comment: I managed to get it kind of working when trying that method, for example I had Pitch Axis = (0, cos(roll), sin(roll)) which works if you roll then pitch. However, if I pitch upwards, then roll, because the pitch axis is dependent on the roll, it not only rolls but it also rotates as the Pitch Axis is changing, I can't figure out the relationship between all three to make this work... any ideas?

Comment: I think that the pitch axis only depends on the 'old' roll axis, not on the 'new' roll axis. That is, each time when you want to do 'sth', you have to do 'Yaw = sth(Yaw); Pitch = sth(Pitch); Roll = sth(Roll); object = sth(object)' where '=' here means 'assigning value', not 'equal'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll certainly give this a go, just like to clarify.. what do you mean by sth? Cheers!

Comment: Sth means any single rotation action by any degree, for example "Yaw 30 degrees" or "Roll 90 degrees". Cheers! =D

Comment: Thanks! So I implemented this I think.. Currently I'm only rotating the pitch axis when it's pitching, otherwise when it's just rolling it uses the old roll value, which means now it DOES work the first time I roll, pitch then roll.. however when I pitch again after the second roll and it updates the pitch axis with the new roll value, it snaps to a different rotation due to the pitch axis not aligning with the object anymore.. thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me some actual numbers here so that I can see what's happening? Thank you.